# Encrypt Saga data in Rebus

Tags: rebus

Is there support for encrypting Saga data using SQL persistence the same way you can encrypt messages?

Sometimes the data that is persisted in the saga are as sensitive as the data in the message so it would be nice if it was possible to also encrypt this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately no, that's currently not supported.

It would probably be pretty easy to implement for your special case though, if you took the code of [the current `SqlServerSagaStorage`](https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus/blob/master/Rebus/Persistence/SqlServer/SqlServerSagaStorage.cs) and changed the `[data]` column to be a `varbinary` and then encrypted/decrypted in the right places.

Let me know if you need any further pointers in doing this :)